# Pygame: get event key string representation

Tags: pygame

I want to let the user make custom key bindings. 
I know which key is pressed through:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           key = event.key
```

That returns a numeric value for the key pressed.

How can I get the unicode string name (e.g. `a`, or in the worst case `K_a`) from this numeric value without having to map the entire keyboard in a dict like

```
{'a' : 97, 'b' : etc}
```

help would be very  much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print the value of a key event, you can do

```
if Event.type == KEYDOWN:
    print Event.unicode
```

Wich will display in the shell 'a' if you pressed a etc... But won't work when pressing "return" key, or other special keys.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I came across this question/answer when I was looking for a similar thing. The event.unicode approach wasn't what I needed because I needed to get the non visible characters as well. I keep looking and found the answer I needed, so I thought it might help the next guy looking for this if I included this here.

An alternative that is similar but also handles things like 'return' and 'left alt' is:

```
pygame.key.name(event.key)
```

"Get the descriptive name of the button from a keyboard button id constant".

You can find it in the docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name).